# is there a way to get a value from a class to outside the class?

Tags: flutter

i have a drop down class which has in its build widget a dropdown widget which on changed it set state the value of selected option to a value in the class.

i used the class in my screen and I don't find a way to use the selected value :(

here is my code

```
class ServiceCategoryDropDownList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ServiceCategoryDropDownList({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ServiceCategoryDropDownList> createState() => _ServiceCategoryDropDownListState();
}
class _ServiceCategoryDropDownListState extends State<ServiceCategoryDropDownList> {
  String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final servicecategories = Provider.of<List<ServiceCategory>> (context);
      return Container(
    child:
      DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child:DropdownButton<String>(
          value: value,
          isExpanded: true,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          iconSize: 36,
          items: servicecategories.map((item){
            print(item.serviceCategoryName);
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item.serviceCategoryID,
              child: Text(item.serviceCategoryName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 14),),

            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() =>this.value = value);
              print(value);
          }
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and here where i call for the class dropdown

```
class ServicesContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const ServicesContent({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ServicesContent> createState() => _ServicesContentState();
}

class _ServicesContentState extends State<ServicesContent> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  
    Scaffold(
      body: StreamProvider<List<ServiceCategory>>.value(
        value: Database().serviceCategory,
        initialData: [],
        child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ServiceCategoryDropDownList(),
                         ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("Add"),
                             onPressed: () => print(ServiceCategoryDropDownList().value)
                         )
])));}
}
```

please any one help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem, do you need to get the selected value out of the dropdown widget? if it is yes, check this explanation and the code

1. Accept a callback property in your widget constructor
2. After that, call your callback passing the selected value
3. Now, you can read the selected value in your ServicesContent as the widget callback parameter

**Dropdown widget**

```
class ServiceCategoryDropDownList extends StatefulWidget {
  // 1. Accept a callback property in you widget constructor
  final Function onChanged;
  const ServiceCategoryDropDownList({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ServiceCategoryDropDownList> createState() =>
      _ServiceCategoryDropDownListState();
}

class _ServiceCategoryDropDownListState
    extends State<ServiceCategoryDropDownList> {
  String? value = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final servicecategories = Provider.of<List<ServiceCategory>>(context);
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: value,
          isExpanded: true,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          iconSize: 36,
          items: servicecategories.map((item) {
            print(item.serviceCategoryName);
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item.serviceCategoryID,
              child: Text(
                item.serviceCategoryName,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() => this.value = value);
            // 2. Call your callback passing the selected value
            widget.onChanged(value);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ServiceContent**

```
class _ServicesContentState extends State<ServicesContent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamProvider<List<ServiceCategory>>.value(
        value: Database().serviceCategory,
        initialData: [],
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ServiceCategoryDropDownList(
              onChanged: (String value) {
                // 3. Now you can read the selected value here and make cool things
                print(value);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Add"),
              // 4. You can't do this ServiceCategoryDropDownList().value, so delete it and get the value at point 3
              onPressed: () => print(ServiceCategoryDropDownList().value),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if you can solve your issue :)